# How to get TypeScript JSX (TSX) syntax highlighting in neovim

Tags: neovim

Neovim has syntax highlighting for TypeScript files (`.ts`) but not ones with JSX extensions (`.tsx`).

What is the simplest way to get syntax highlighting for `tsx` files?

Answer (score 2):

Many plugins provide syntax highlighting for TypeScript. Here’s a list of plugins:

- [Typescript-Vim](https://github.com/leafgarland/typescript-vim)
- [Yats-Vim](https://github.com/herringtondarkholme/yats.vim)
- [Vim-JSX-Pretty](https://github.com/maxmellon/vim-jsx-pretty)
- [Vim-JSX-Typescript](https://github.com/peitalin/vim-jsx-typescript)

Syntax highlighting and autocompletion are also provided by coc(conquer of completion), you just need to install the plugin `coc-tsserver`.

If this doesn't answer you question then you might want to checkout Chris's Channnel [here](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCS97tchJDq17Qms3cux8wcA).